# Sound doesn't work anymore after replacing RAM

Tags: linux, audio, debian, alsa

today, I replaced one old RAM module with two newer, bigger ones, but now, the sound doesn't seem to work anymore. Already ran `alsaconf` and it didn't help.

Output of `lspci` for the audio device:

```
00:07.0 Audio device: nVidia Corporation MCP67 High Definition Audio (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Giga-byte Technology Device a002
 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz+ UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0 (500ns min, 1250ns max)
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 21
 Region 0: Memory at f5100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: [44] Power Management version 2
  Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0-,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
  Status: D0 PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
 Capabilities: [50] Message Signalled Interrupts: Mask+ 64bit+ Queue=0/0 Enable-
  Address: 0000000000000000  Data: 0000
  Masking: 00000000  Pending: 00000000
 Capabilities: [6c] HyperTransport: MSI Mapping Enable+ Fixed+
 Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
 Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

The audio device is onboard and has six configurable outputs, two or so are also capable of being an input (if I remember it correctly), but I don't know how to control it under linux. Does somebody know how/whether replacing the RAM could be related to my problem and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Did you possibly knock something loose while the machine was open?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Well, I obviously don't know it, but I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it out - seems like my machine dedided that it was time to return to the good old values and reset the audio output settings to factory default. Sorry for the unnecessary noise.